# Type (namespace) of returned object is different from expected - auto generated classes in web service client contain duplicate of class

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jaxb, wsdl

I work in NetBeans 7.2. I created class Laptop from xml using JAXB binding, then I made jar from this project and added it to Web Service libraries - I wanted to use functions from Laptop class as functions in web service.
In web service client, some classes were automathicly generated from functions in ws, like for example getall(), that returns list of laptops.

```
@WebMethod
public List<Laptop> getAll() {

    return l.getAll();
}
```

Apart from GetAll.java class in web service client was generated also GetAllResponse.java class, that contains  Return class inside - Return is the same as Laptop class - only name is different.
So, every class in web service client, that was generated from function that returns Laptop or list of Laptops and has in the name word "Response" contains class Return (using @WebResult(name="Laptop"), the name can be changed from Return into Laptop)

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name="Laptop")
public Laptop getById(int id) {
    return l.getById(id);
}
```

Having implementation of laptop in several places I have problem with namespaces of returned objects to client.
As in the picture below, expected object is: DAO.client.Laptop but DAO.client.GetByIdResponse.Laptop is sent. What I should change to have only one implementation of Laptop in client or to avoid ambiguity in type of returned object?

Pict1: Problem with namespaces
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/208/47894110.jpg/

Pict2:Laptop.java in several places
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/24881074.png/